# Waiting for async call to finish so I can use the result, its not working?

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I tried querying Firestore using .get():

```
//Cloud function to perform leaderboard calculation
exports.scheduledLeaderboardFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('00 21 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/Los_Angeles') 
  .onRun(async (context) => {

    var globalPostsArray = [];

    try {
        await admin.firestore()
        .collection('globalPosts')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {

            if(querySnapshot.exists) {
    
                querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {

                const { 
                    
                    //Fields
                    //Removed

                    } = res.data();
        
                    globalPostsArray.push({
                        
                        //Fields
                        //Removed

                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("Data doesn't exist") <-------- This error is thrown
            }
            return null
        })
        .then(() => {
            if (globalPostsArray.length > 0) {
                console.log(globalPostsArray)
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("length not greater than 0")
            }
            return null;
        })
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    return null;

});
```

but in the firebase cloud log, I get the following error printed:

```
Error: Data doesn't exist
```

Which means querySnapshot doesn't exist when I use .get() (the error is thrown).

**globalPosts, the collection I am querying, is NOT empty**

if I can make .get() to work, that would work for my issue, since I am not waiting for updates which is what .onSnapshot() is good for.

summary: onSnapshot() worked for fetching the data from Firestore, but I can't use .then() to wait for the data so I can finish up the work. get() isn't working, but I can use .then() to wait for the collection if it does work.

How can I fix my issue?

EDIT: changed the function to this, but its still not working

```
//Cloud function to perform leaderboard calculation
exports.scheduledLeaderboardFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('00 21 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/Los_Angeles') 
  .onRun(async (context) => {


    try {
        await admin.firestore().collection('globalPosts').orderBy("date_created", "desc")
        .get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            if(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                });
                return null
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("Data doesn't exist")
            }
        })
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }


    return null;

});
```

Proof globalPosts isn't empty:

[image]

Same error:

```
Error: Data doesn't exist
```

Comment: The function passed to `onSnapshot` happens at some point in the future, when the data is eventually fetched, and then potentially more when the data changes. You have the data from Firestore in that callback, why can't you do your calculations in `onSnapshot`?

Comment: O wait, this is a cloud function? You can't open a listener and have it stay open in a serverless function. Functions are not supposed to be long lasting.

Comment: Yeah, I used onSnapshot first, but then figured get() is probably the way to go. With get(), my request is throwing the error. @windowsill its really odd because I've used get() in a ton of other places in the front end and haven't had this issue, but I have problems using get() in the cloud function

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with `.get()`, but don't mix async syntax.

```
  const shortSnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
    .collection("stuff")
    .where("stuff", "==", "new")
    .limit(1)
    .get();

  if (shortSnapshot.empty) {
    console.error("No stuff");
    return response.sendStatus(404);
  }

  console.log(shortSnapshot.docs[0].data());
```

Comment: will shortSnapshot be an array that holds the entire collection?

Comment: No it's a Firestore query result object. You can find out more in the Firestore docs, but you can access each document in the query result as outlined above (`snapshot.docs.map(d => d.data())`).

Comment: Still getting the error for no stuff, even though the db isn't empty

Answer (score 0):

There is no .then for .onSnapShot - it *attaches* a Listener Function, and returns synchronously, with no data - it does NOT return a promise.

the anonymous function you created and passed - it begins `(querySnapshot) => {` is called with a querySnapshot as it's argument *when* the Listener is triggered.  Judging by the other parts of the code, you're attempting a cloud function?  As a general rule, listeners are NOT the correct approach for a Cloud Function, as these functions are intended to be short-lived.

The message you are shown is precisely what would be expected if your collection `'globalPosts'` were empty - and you show nothing here to indicate that this is an error.

Comment: globalPosts is not empty - sorry, will add that clarification in the question. But I understand now that onSnapshot is not the right way to go, .get() is. regardless, .get() is not working

Comment: You've shown there are documents, but NOT what is contained in them.  If you "sortby", or if you include a "where" clause, it will ONLY return documents that **have** those fields.  If you don't "see" it (whether in Firestore console or console.log messages), you don't "know" it.

Comment: I have figured out the issue. Added the answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the try, catch fixed my issue!

```
await admin.firestore().collection('globalPosts').orderBy("date_created", "desc")
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    if(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
        return null
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Data doesn't exist")
    }
})
```

The error of "data doesn't exist" is no longer an issue